# Request: Links to projects attempting the implementing of a Google Wave server

Tags: google-wave

[Rafe Needleman at CNet](http://news.cnet.com/8301-17939_109-10252579-2.html) writes that his knowledgable sources say it is incredibly challenging making a realtime synchronization engine work at scale, and I do not doubt it.

Perhaps, though, a realtime synchronization engine conformant with Google Wave protocol which is limited to 50 messages per day from a total participant pool of 50 users would be would be merely an occasion of long nights and soul-searching.  It would certainly be useful for those who have no sandbox account.

I found one project (through a [Twitter search](http://twitter.com/purserj/status/2026821377), thanks purserj) named [pygowave-server](http://code.google.com/p/pygowave-server/).  Are there others?

Answer (score 1):

Via twitter search as well: http://www.watblog.com/2009/07/27/cant-wait-for-google-wave-try-these-two-nifty-tools-instead/